# Where's unminified version of Bootstrap 3 docs.min.js

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, unminify

I would like to check the original version of this file : https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/docs/assets/js/docs.min.js . Tried to search through project but seems no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`docs/assets/js/docs.min.js`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/docs/assets/js/docs.min.js) is built from [`docs/assets/js/_vendor/holder.js`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/docs/assets/js/_vendor/holder.js) and [`docs/assets/js/_src/application.js`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/docs/assets/js/_src/application.js). See [`Gruntfile.js`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/Gruntfile.js#L135-L145).